# Javascript/AJAX not working in Opera, works perfect in FF/IE/Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, opera, getelementbyid, xmlhttprequest

I currently have this Javascript in a file named getresults.js:

```js
function getItems(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("getItems").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("getItems").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/include/retrieveitems.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

It's called upon by this event:

```
onclick="getItems('all')"
```

It works perfectly in Firefox, IE, Chrome.. but Opera refuses to work. A very small percentage of my visitors are Opera users, but still.. I'd rather have it work. A live url can be found here: http://tf2g.com/gallery

If anyone can help, much obliged!

Comment: Horrible, horrible indentation! I know it's w3schools, but you're still guilty for leaving it so :-p

Comment: Also, the AJAX request itself works. Yes, even in Opera. Try logging `status` and `responseText`. It's a bit difficult to debug your page without mirroring it on my computer.

Comment: "Even in Opera"? Opera rocks. I set up this code locally and everything worked fine. Agree - confirm first that the callback doesn't fire.

Comment: @Utkanos Eh, that came out wrong ;) I just wanted to emphasize that I was testing in Opera. Sure it rocks! My primary browser :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this fails is that the event handler is not calling your getItems() method at all. It **sees the document.getItems() method from Opera's Microdata support** ( http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html ) and calls that instead. It's a question of JavaScript scope: both the element itself and its document is in scope, so methods/properties defined here will be able to hide methods / properties you define in the global scope.

Be happy that Opera implemented Microdata early so you noticed this :)

The simplest fix is to rename your function to avoid name collision with Microdata. You can also use addEventListener() instead of writing onclick="" in the markup - if you do the scope of the function is the scope it is created in, so you don't run into such gotchas.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  for( var i=0,l;l=document.links[i]; i++ )if( l.hash){
    l.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
      getItems(this.hash.substr(1));
    }, false);
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: Ah, I see, it worked! Renaming it workedl ike a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I debugged your link a bit and found out that there's no problem with the AJAX request.
In fact, there's an unhandled exception in jquery.min.js file which prevents other javascript code from running.

Steps I did:
I opened Opera DragonFly (Ctrl+Shft+I), which is firebug-a-like and refresh the page. I inserted break-points in 'getItems()' and saw that the code didn't reach there.
Via Dragonfly console I wrote "getItems('all');" and the ajax went as expected.

O

Comment: I see.. any clue what that unhandled exception is? And why is Opera the only one that's acting up? Thanks for your answer! --edit: updated jquery.min.js to 1.8.0, no joy either.