# Why javascript:void(0) is not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, anchor

Why is this simple link example not working in Firefox? It is working in IE and Chrome.
[js fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/u6bKr/)
I am using windows XP. My Firefox version is 16.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My research for `getItems()` showed what in some situations this function is defined as *native function*. I don't know why. To avoid this trouble try to rename function `getItems`.

http://jsfiddle.net/u6bKr/3/

**UPDATE:**

As specified in comment by Boris Zbarsky this trouble can be also avoided when adding `window.` before `getItems()` (e.g. `window.getItems()`).

Comment: Problem not in jQuery. My example does not use any framework. Add `alert(getItems);` inside `onclick` attribute of anchor. Alert showed `function getItems(){ [native code] }` . This function is visible in FireFox (checked in FF16b) only inside of `onclick` attribute code.

Comment: yes, you are right :- i got one more helpful link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097176/javascript-ajax-not-working-in-opera-works-perfect-in-ff-ie-chrome

Comment: getItems is defined as a "native" function because of http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#dom-document-getitems and in particular using `window.getItems()` in the event handler will work.

Answer (score 3):

Your fiddle sample shouldn't work in any browser because you've defined the `getItems()` method inside the `onload` handler that is the jsfiddle default (as set on the left-hand side) which in turn means that it is not in scope from the inline `onclick="getItems()"` attribute.

It works in FF if you fix that by selecting `no wrap (head)` instead of `onLoad`, thus making your function global: http://jsfiddle.net/u6bKr/1/

(Note that this has nothing to do with `href="javascript:void(0);"`)

Comment: :- i changed  left-hand side to no wrap(head) and it is working in IE but not in mozilla . please help..